# Pyinstaller creating empty dist folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

I have `python 3.9.x` and Pyinstaller 4.9 is compatible with all python versions. I am also running on Ubuntu 21.10. My python project contains one .py file and one .kv file. I have tried it also with only the .py file but still the dist folder is empty.

This is what I have tried :

pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py

I also tried running these commands with `sudo` because I was desperate. 
I tried uninstalling it : `sudo pip uninstall pyinstaller` and the reinstalling it again.

I use kivy in my project and I want to convert my python file into an exe so that my teacher won't have to download kivy. He has a Mac by the way.

```
29 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.9
29 INFO: Python: 3.9.7
30 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.13.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.34
30 INFO: wrote /home/filzo/School/Lang Prog/Devoir 1/devoir_1_GUI.spec
32 INFO: UPX is not available.
32 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/filzo/School/Lang Prog/Devoir 1']
153 INFO: checking Analysis
153 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
153 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
154 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
162 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1624 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
1624 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.9'
3532 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3621 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3641 INFO: Analyzing /home/filzo/School/Lang Prog/Devoir 1/devoir_1_GUI.py
4728 INFO: Processing module hooks...
4729 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4729 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-kivy.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/filzo/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-02-06_69.txt
4733 INFO: [Logger      ] Record log in /home/filzo/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-02-06_69.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
4733 INFO: [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
4733 INFO: [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43) 
[GCC 11.2.0]
4733 INFO: [Python      ] v3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43) 
[GCC 11.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
4733 INFO: [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
4734 INFO: [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/filzo/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-02-06_70.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.7 (default, Sep 10 2021, 14:59:43) 
[GCC 11.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
4844 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
4844 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
     sys.exit(run())
4845 WARNING: stderr:     sys.exit(run())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 124, in run
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 124, in run
     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
4845 WARNING: stderr:     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
4845 WARNING: stderr:     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 793, in main
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 793, in main
     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
4845 WARNING: stderr:     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 725, in build
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 725, in build
     exec(code, spec_namespace)
4845 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, spec_namespace)
   File "/home/filzo/School/Lang Prog/Devoir 1/devoir_1_GUI.spec", line 7, in <module>
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/home/filzo/School/Lang Prog/Devoir 1/devoir_1_GUI.spec", line 7, in <module>
     a = Analysis(['devoir_1_GUI.py'],
4845 WARNING: stderr:     a = Analysis(['devoir_1_GUI.py'],
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
4845 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
     self.__postinit__()
4846 WARNING: stderr:     self.__postinit__()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
     self.assemble()
4846 WARNING: stderr:     self.assemble()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
     self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
4846 WARNING: stderr:     self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
     module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
4846 WARNING: stderr:     module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
     self._load_hook_module()
4846 WARNING: stderr:     self._load_hook_module()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
     self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
4846 WARNING: stderr:     self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
4846 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
     return mod_loader.load_module()
4847 WARNING: stderr:     return mod_loader.load_module()
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 529, in _check_name_wrapper
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 529, in _check_name_wrapper
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1029, in load_module
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1029, in load_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 854, in load_module
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 854, in load_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 274, in _load_module_shim
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 274, in _load_module_shim
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
4847 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py", line 21, in <module>
4848 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py", line 21, in <module>
     hiddenimports = get_deps_all()['hiddenimports']
4848 WARNING: stderr:     hiddenimports = get_deps_all()['hiddenimports']
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 275, in get_deps_all
4848 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 275, in get_deps_all
     'binaries': _find_gst_binaries(),
4848 WARNING: stderr:     'binaries': _find_gst_binaries(),
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 354, in _find_gst_binaries
4848 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 354, in _find_gst_binaries
     gst_plugin_path = _find_gst_plugin_path()
4848 WARNING: stderr:     gst_plugin_path = _find_gst_plugin_path()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 342, in _find_gst_plugin_path
4849 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/pyinstaller_hooks/__init__.py", line 342, in _find_gst_plugin_path
     match = re.search(r'\s+(\S+libgstcoreelements\.\S+)', stdoutdata)
4849 WARNING: stderr:     match = re.search(r'\s+(\S+libgstcoreelements\.\S+)', stdoutdata)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
4849 WARNING: stderr:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
4849 WARNING: stderr:     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
 TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
4849 WARNING: stderr: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the desktop's terminal, I used Pycharm's terminal and it worked. I think it's because Pycharm uses venv.